# CSS :target another element

Tags: css, css-selectors, target

Is it possible to target also another element like in the example ?

```
<a href="#AAA">click</a>
<div id="AAA">some content</div>
<div id="BBB">some content</div>
```

Something like...

```
#AAA:target #BBB{color:red}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for I think you he might want `#AAA:target,#BBB:target{color:red}`? What do you mean by `target also`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you could use the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/F82mZ/)

```
#AAA:target + #BBB {
    color:red
}
```

Depending on the markup, it might be better to use the [general sibling combinator, `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/VtDDg/)